# Can't have italics in math mode and serif in text at the same time

Tags: beamer, sans-serif, textcomp

I am working with the following and I get very nice text serif fonts, which I want to keep, but I also get these fonts in math mode, which means math text doesn't show up in italics, as I want it to.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{ucl}

 \setbeamercolor{banner}{bg=black,fg=orange}
 \setbeamercolor{banner stripe}{bg=orange,fg=black}
 \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
\setbeamersize{description width=2em}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\vspace{-2ex}} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usefonttheme[hoptionsi]{serif}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{syllogism}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{olive}{rgb}{0.3, 0.4, .1}
    \definecolor{fore}{RGB}{249,242,215}
    \definecolor{back}{RGB}{51,51,51}
    \definecolor{title}{RGB}{255,0,90}
    \definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}
    \definecolor{gold}{rgb}{1.,0.84,0.}
    \definecolor{JungleGreen}{cmyk}{0.99,0,0.52,0}
    \definecolor{BlueGreen}{cmyk}{0.85,0,0.33,0}
    \definecolor{RawSienna}{cmyk}{0,0.72,1,0.45}
    \definecolor{Magenta}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
    \newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\magenta}[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\yellow}[1]{\textcolor{gold}{#1}}

    \newtheorem{rough}{Provisional Definition}
    \newtheorem*{chara}{Characterisation}
    \newtheorem*{observation}{Observation}

    \newcommand{\Lp}{\mathcal{L}_1}
        \renewcommand{\iff}{\leftrightarrow}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\title{Introduction to Logic 1}
\subtitle{Lecture 2: The Language of Propositional Logic - Syntax}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frame{
\frametitle{Bracketing conventions}

\begin{observation}[conventions in $\Lp$]
\pause
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textnormal{$\wedge $ and $\vee $ bind more strongly than  $\rightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow $:
\pause     ($P\rightarrow Q\wedge R$) abbreviates $(P\rightarrow (Q\wedge R))$} \pause 

  \item \textnormal{One may drop brackets on strings of $\land$s or strings of $\lor$s: \pause
  $(P\wedge Q\wedge R)$ abbreviates $((P\wedge Q)\wedge R)$}

  \item \textnormal{One may drop outer brackets:  \pause
     $P\wedge (Q\rightarrow\neg P_4)$ abbreviates $(P\wedge (Q\rightarrow\neg P_4))$} \pause

\end{itemize}
 \end{observation}
}
\end{document}
```

I tried different combinations, removing professionalfonts, textcomp and serif, but nothing works. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a complete example, i.e. some minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled and illustrates the issue.

Comment: Welcome! I tried to complete your example (by adding `\documentclass{beamer}` and a sample frame) but I can't reproduce the issue - both `$x+y$` and `$ \mathit{abc}$` are in italics (only `$ \text{abc} $` is serif, but that is expected).

Comment: Thanks for this. I figured it out. It's the UCL theme that's interfering with my math mode (\usetheme{ucl}).

Comment: I removed the eulervm package from the beamerthemeucl.sty file and it worked!

Comment: @LaviniaPicollo Great to hear you were able to solve your problem! Would you like to write a short answer?

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer

Answer (score 2):

The eulervm package takes italics from math mode away. Since I wanted the italics, I removed the package from the .sty file I was using.